# I'm testing SOLID STATE write failure times (c code) and the device isn't failing

Tags: c, linux, io

**Turns out I misinterpreted wear leveling, I initially thought by accessing the drive as RAW I would lose this feature but as its a feature on the controller this explains why i am hitting millions of writes to the 'logical sector' I am testing**

I am writing an application where I will be utilizing a RAW disk partition like a circular buffer, ie no filesystem.

I need somewhere to keep track of my read/write buffer heads that is persistent across boots, I was thinking i can create another partition to store these 2 pointers.

But I am worried about how many times I can write to a sector in the devices SOLID state drive before the sector dies so I wrote the code below to hammer a single sector and see how quickly it fails.

1. create random block (512 bytes)
2. write to sector 0 using pwrite
3. read block from sector 0 using pread
4. compare each byte
5. exit when difference found.

but it has been running for millions of sector writes now!!

I would have expected it to fail somewhere standard like between 10,000-100,000 times?

I'm using pread/pwrite as below with a random buffer each loop and a comparison of both buffers afterwards.

```
void WriteBlock(const char* device, unsigned char* dataBlock, size_t sector, int size)
{
    int fd = open(device, O_WRONLY);
    if(fd <= 0)
    {
        std::cout << "error opening " << device << " '" << strerror(errno) << "'\r\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ssize_t r = pwrite(fd, dataBlock, size, sector*SECTOR_SIZE);
    if (r<=0 || r<size)
    {
        std::cout << "failure writing '" << strerror(errno) << "'\r\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    close(fd);
}

void ReadBlock(const char* device, unsigned char* dataBlock, size_t sector, int size)
{
    int fd = open(device, O_RDONLY);
    if(fd <= 0)
    {
        std::cout << "error opening " << device << "\r\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ssize_t r = pread(fd, dataBlock, size, sector*SECTOR_SIZE);
    if (r<=0 || r<size)
    {
        std::cout << "failure writing '" << strerror(errno) << "'\r\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    close(fd);
}
```

the code just keeps on running with the write buffer equal to the read buffer every time.

FYI i'm not comparing the write buffer to itself! if i hard code a value into the read buffer it catches this and interprets as a failure.

Comment: It might be a better idea to create your own file-like system in the partition, one where you store crucial data in multiple places (like e.g. the superblocks on an ext4-formatted disk). When you "open" the device, read your "superblock" from all locations and compare. If one is faulty then rewrite it, check the result, and if still faulty mark that block as invalid in a bitmap (also stored on disk, possibly in redundant locations).

Comment: Not sure but, is there no controller inside SSD that mask the hardware? I mean, the SSD controller isn't in charge of giving some level abstraction (garbage collection, error correcting, bad blocks, etc)? In that case writing to an address may not be in the same physical location on the drive...

Comment: Yes, read about **wear leveling** in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive

Comment: I was thinking of having a separate partition for the pointer data and count how many times I write to each sector before moving on to the next one in order. I could then skip to using another sector every say 2000 writes (which should be well under the worst case). i could then store which sector i was currently using in another sector that is only updated every sector change, ie 2000 writes so that should last much longer.... but below somebody mentioned that wear leveling is at the device level - i assumed it was at the filesystem level - this problem may have just gone away!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would have expected it to fail somewhere standard like between 10,000-100,000 times?

Most solid state drives have wear levelling. What this means is that when you write to logical block 0 the device says "Hey, the old data in logical block 0 is getting overwritten, so I can just pretend a completely different physical block is now logical block 0". By continually writing to the same logical block, you can be writing to many completely different physical blocks.

To defeat wear leveling (and actually write to the same physical block) you have to convince the device that all other blocks are in use. This isn't possible because there's spare capacity. For example, for a 1 TiB device you can fill all 1 TiB of logical blocks with data (without doing any "trim", etc), but there might be an extra 512 GiB of spare space and your writes to the same logical block will be spread across that 512 GiB of spare space; and by the time you actually see an error it may mean that every block in that 512 GiB of spare space has failed (and not just one block).

If you know how much spare space there actually is, then you might be able to do calculations based on that - e.g. if there's 1 thousand spare blocks and you do 1 billion writes before seeing an error, then you might be able to say "1 billion writes / 1 thousand blocks = 1 million writes to each physical block".

Now, imagine you're a manufacturer and you've got a 1000 GiB drive. You decide to sell it as a consumer drive (with the assumption that the drive will be mostly empty and wear leveling will be able to work well) and that you can say it's a 900 GiB drive (with 100 GiB of spare blocks) that will fail after 10000 writes. Then you decide to also sell the exact same drive as an enterprise drive (with the assumption that the drive will probably be full and wear leveling won't be so effective) and that you can say it's a 900 GiB drive (with 100 GiB of spare blocks) that will fail after 2000 writes. Then you decide you can increase the amount of spare space, and also sell the "mostly the same" drive as an 500 GiB enterprise drive (with 500 GiB of spare blocks) that will fail after 20000 writes.

Next; imagine that you test 1000 identical drives (with the software you're writing) and measure "20000 writes before failure on average, under the specific conditions used for testing (e.g. with the rest of the logical blocks all free/empty)". This information is mostly useless - if someone uses the same drive under different conditions (e.g. with less logical blocks free/empty) then it'll fail sooner (or later) than you said it would.

For a (potentially better) alternative; you might be able to use information obtained from "S.M.A.R.T." (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T. ). Unfortunately some of the most useful pieces of information you can get is manufacturer specific (e.g. Used Reserved Block Count Total, Unused Reserved Block Count Total), and some devices (USB flash) don't support it at all.

Comment: well that would solve the problem for me! 
I thought wear leveling was at the OS/Filesystem level and as such by writing directly/RAW i would lose that functionality and be essentially... hammering the same spot over and over.
if the device handles wear leveling then i have nothing to worry about, i will leave a big empty space on the disk.

Comment: I guess if i only use a subset of the disk (say a 50% partition) then the disk wont be full and over its life spare blocks that could have been used for the other 50% wont be used at all and my heavily used logical sector 0 can 'borrow' them, in a similar way to an enterprise drive above

Comment: I have asked a further question related to this regarding "does wear leveling work at disk or partition level".

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61522796/sd-does-wear-leveling-work-at-the-partition-or-disk-level