# SD does wear leveling work at the partition or disk level

Tags: c, linux, io, disk

I wrote this question previously [I'm testing SOLID STATE write failure times (c code) and the device isn't failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54180391/im-testing-solid-state-write-failure-times-c-code-and-the-device-isnt-failin) and it was brilliantly answered by Brendan.

I was basically asking about writing to an SD card many times and when it would fail as I am writing an application that will be writing data to an SD card for many years.

My follow up question is does wear leveling work at the disk or partition level.

If for ease of setting my application up, say i wanted 3 partitions

ie for examples sake a 16GB card

```
[partion0 2GB]
[partion1 1GB]
[partion2 1GB]
[12GB free unpartitioned space]
```

would the 12GB free unpartitioned space be available to all 3 partitions as 'user level over-provisioning ' (i know the physical card will have proper over-provisioning extra space of its own...)

or would the 12gb be ignored and only the free space in each partition would be available to that particular partition for wear leveling (excluding the cards extra space for this purpose).

I just want to know if say i left 50% of the card empty and split the card into a number of partitions that I am not affecting the wear leveling algorithm, otherwise I will have one partition and manage the data myself another way.

for clarity

i'm going to create 3 partitions with fdisk and use them RAW as RingBuffers, also it will be a brand new SD card. if those 3 partitions total 50% of the disk, leaving 50% unallocated space, when i save/update 1 SECTOR in a partition, is the unallocated disk space available/used by the controller for saving this SECTOR DATA as it is saving over the whole disk, or will it only save to other free sectors within that partition?

Comment: I suppose it depends whether a fresh, new SD card from the manufacturer already has real storage blocks mapped to the sectors, or whether they are not mapped until written to.

Comment: Or in other words, whether the unpartitioned space is hogging storage blocks that have been mapped to it or not.

Comment: I would format (clear) it first (somehow) as formatting would 'touch' all the blocks the disk might appear 'full' of empty data, not sure. more appropriately i might need to run the manufacturers TRIM/RESET tool.. to get a truely reset disk - BUT assume it is totally empty

Comment: Unlike SSDs, most SD cards don't support TRIM/DISCARD. (I don't know whether any of them do. Maybe high-end, expensive ones?)

Comment: A "quick" format (as opposed to a "full" format) shouldn't write to all the blocks, only the blocks that are part of the initial filesystem control information.

Comment: this thread explains all... https://superuser.com/a/1081730/985052